# Ubuntu freezes after inactivity

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04

I made a clean ubuntu 20.04 install 2 weeks ago, but since day 1 the OS hangs after some inactivity. How can I debug it?

- It's fully updated
- Dual boot (windows 10) works fine, default grub configured everything
- This OS replaces a 2 year old ubuntu 18.04 that was working fine
- I disabled screen locking because I thought it was causing my issue (I locked the PC and 5 minutes after it was frozen). But the issue persists
- I'm attaching part of my syslog. I was away from keyboard for about 2 hours and it was frozen when I got back. But I can't find any useful information in this log.

  - Hardware is a desktop ryzen 3 1200, 8GB RAM, nvidia 980gtx, a small SSD and a largelly unused HDD.

Here's some of my syslog (cajueiro is the hostname):

```
May 30 08:00:19 cajueiro boinc[1281]: message repeated 735 times: [ No protocol specified]
May 30 08:00:20 cajueiro gnome-shell[2823]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x4400007 specified for 0x440003e.
May 30 08:00:20 cajueiro boinc[1281]: No protocol specified
May 30 08:09:01 cajueiro boinc[1281]: message repeated 517 times: [ No protocol specified]
May 30 08:09:01 cajueiro CRON[16846]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
May 30 08:09:02 cajueiro boinc[1281]: No protocol specified
May 30 08:09:25 cajueiro boinc[1281]: message repeated 23 times: [ No protocol specified]
May 30 08:09:25 cajueiro systemd[1]: Starting Clean php session files...
May 30 08:09:26 cajueiro systemd[1]: phpsessionclean.service: Succeeded.
May 30 08:09:26 cajueiro systemd[1]: Finished Clean php session files.
May 30 08:09:26 cajueiro boinc[1281]: No protocol specified
May 30 08:15:49 cajueiro boinc[1281]: message repeated 381 times: [ No protocol specified]
May 30 08:15:50 cajueiro gnome-shell[2823]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x4400007 specified for 0x4400044.
May 30 08:15:50 cajueiro boinc[1281]: No protocol specified
May 30 08:17:01 cajueiro boinc[1281]: message repeated 70 times: [ No protocol specified]
May 30 08:17:01 cajueiro CRON[17558]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
May 30 08:17:02 cajueiro boinc[1281]: No protocol specified
May 30 08:26:15 cajueiro boinc[1281]: message repeated 550 times: [ No protocol specified]
May 30 08:26:16 cajueiro telegramdesktop.desktop[7951]: QTextCursor::setPosition: Position '-1' out of range
May 30 08:26:16 cajueiro boinc[1281]: No protocol specified
May 30 08:26:25 cajueiro boinc[1281]: message repeated 9 times: [ No protocol specified]
May 30 08:26:26 cajueiro gnome-shell[2823]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x4400007 specified for 0x440004a.
May 30 08:26:26 cajueiro gnome-shell[2823]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x4400007 specified for 0x4400050.
May 30 08:26:26 cajueiro gnome-shell[2823]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x4400007 specified for 0x4400053.
May 30 08:26:26 cajueiro boinc[1281]: No protocol specified
May 30 08:27:16 cajueiro boinc[1281]: message repeated 49 times: [ No protocol specified]
May 30 08:27:16 cajueiro dbus-daemon[843]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.bluez' unit='dbus-org.bluez.service' requested by ':1.175' (uid=1000 pid=18669 comm="/snap/code/33/usr/share/code/code --no-sandbox . " label="snap.code.code (complain)")
May 30 08:27:16 cajueiro systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
May 30 08:27:17 cajueiro boinc[1281]: No protocol specified
May 30 08:27:41 cajueiro boinc[1281]: message repeated 24 times: [ No protocol specified]
May 30 08:27:42 cajueiro boinc[1281]: No protocol specified
May 30 08:30:01 cajueiro boinc[1281]: message repeated 138 times: [ No protocol specified]
May 30 08:30:01 cajueiro CRON[19308]: (root) CMD ([ -x /etc/init.d/anacron ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d anacron start >/dev/null; fi)
May 30 08:30:02 cajueiro boinc[1281]: No protocol specified
May 30 08:30:17 cajueiro boinc[1281]: message repeated 15 times: [ No protocol specified]
May 30 08:30:17 cajueiro systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
May 30 08:30:17 cajueiro anacron[19323]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2020-05-30
May 30 08:30:17 cajueiro anacron[19323]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
May 30 08:30:17 cajueiro systemd[1]: anacron.service: Succeeded.
May 30 08:30:18 cajueiro boinc[1281]: No protocol specified
May 30 08:30:20 cajueiro boinc[1281]: message repeated 2 times: [ No protocol specified]
May 30 08:30:20 cajueiro gnome-shell[2823]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x4400007 specified for 0x440005c.
May 30 08:30:21 cajueiro boinc[1281]: No protocol specified
May 30 08:31:47 cajueiro boinc[1281]: message repeated 86 times: [ No protocol specified]
May 30 08:31:48 cajueiro gnome-shell[2823]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x4400007 specified for 0x4400062.
May 30 08:31:48 cajueiro boinc[1281]: No protocol specified
May 30 08:32:19 cajueiro boinc[1281]: message repeated 30 times: [ No protocol specified]
May 30 08:32:19 cajueiro gnome-shell[2823]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x4400007 specified for 0x4400068.
May 30 08:32:20 cajueiro boinc[1281]: No protocol specified
May 30 08:39:00 cajueiro boinc[1281]: message repeated 398 times: [ No protocol specified]
May 30 08:39:01 cajueiro CRON[20024]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
May 30 08:39:01 cajueiro boinc[1281]: No protocol specified
May 30 08:39:25 cajueiro boinc[1281]: message repeated 23 times: [ No protocol specified]
May 30 08:39:25 cajueiro systemd[1]: Starting Clean php session files...
May 30 08:39:26 cajueiro boinc[1281]: No protocol specified
May 30 08:39:26 cajueiro systemd[1]: phpsessionclean.service: Succeeded.
May 30 08:39:26 cajueiro systemd[1]: Finished Clean php session files.
May 30 08:39:27 cajueiro boinc[1281]: No protocol specified
May 30 08:47:48 cajueiro boinc[1281]: message repeated 498 times: [ No protocol specified]
May 30 08:47:48 cajueiro NetworkManager[844]: <info>  [1590839268.9873] dhcp4 (enp37s0): option dhcp_lease_time      => '7200'
May 30 08:47:48 cajueiro NetworkManager[844]: <info>  [1590839268.9874] dhcp4 (enp37s0): option domain_name_servers  => '192.168.1.1'
May 30 08:47:48 cajueiro NetworkManager[844]: <info>  [1590839268.9874] dhcp4 (enp37s0): option expiry               => '1590846468'
May 30 08:47:48 cajueiro NetworkManager[844]: <info>  [1590839268.9874] dhcp4 (enp37s0): option ip_address           => '192.168.1.104'
May 30 08:47:48 cajueiro NetworkManager[844]: <info>  [1590839268.9874] dhcp4 (enp37s0): option requested_broadcast_address => '1'
May 30 08:47:48 cajueiro NetworkManager[844]: <info>  [1590839268.9874] dhcp4 (enp37s0): option requested_domain_name => '1'
May 30 08:47:48 cajueiro NetworkManager[844]: <info>  [1590839268.9874] dhcp4 (enp37s0): option requested_domain_name_servers => '1'
May 30 08:47:48 cajueiro dbus-daemon[843]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.11' (uid=0 pid=844 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
May 30 08:47:48 cajueiro NetworkManager[844]: <info>  [1590839268.9875] dhcp4 (enp37s0): option requested_domain_search => '1'
May 30 08:47:48 cajueiro NetworkManager[844]: <info>  [1590839268.9875] dhcp4 (enp37s0): option requested_host_name  => '1'
May 30 08:47:48 cajueiro NetworkManager[844]: <info>  [1590839268.9875] dhcp4 (enp37s0): option requested_interface_mtu => '1'
May 30 08:47:48 cajueiro NetworkManager[844]: <info>  [1590839268.9875] dhcp4 (enp37s0): option requested_ms_classless_static_routes => '1'
May 30 08:47:48 cajueiro NetworkManager[844]: <info>  [1590839268.9875] dhcp4 (enp37s0): option requested_nis_domain => '1'
May 30 08:47:48 cajueiro NetworkManager[844]: <info>  [1590839268.9875] dhcp4 (enp37s0): option requested_nis_servers => '1'
May 30 08:47:48 cajueiro NetworkManager[844]: <info>  [1590839268.9875] dhcp4 (enp37s0): option requested_ntp_servers => '1'
May 30 08:47:48 cajueiro NetworkManager[844]: <info>  [1590839268.9876] dhcp4 (enp37s0): option requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes => '1'
May 30 08:47:48 cajueiro NetworkManager[844]: <info>  [1590839268.9876] dhcp4 (enp37s0): option requested_root_path  => '1'
May 30 08:47:48 cajueiro NetworkManager[844]: <info>  [1590839268.9876] dhcp4 (enp37s0): option requested_routers    => '1'
May 30 08:47:48 cajueiro NetworkManager[844]: <info>  [1590839268.9876] dhcp4 (enp37s0): option requested_static_routes => '1'
May 30 08:47:48 cajueiro NetworkManager[844]: <info>  [1590839268.9876] dhcp4 (enp37s0): option requested_subnet_mask => '1'
May 30 08:47:48 cajueiro NetworkManager[844]: <info>  [1590839268.9876] dhcp4 (enp37s0): option requested_time_offset => '1'
May 30 08:47:48 cajueiro NetworkManager[844]: <info>  [1590839268.9876] dhcp4 (enp37s0): option requested_wpad       => '1'
May 30 08:47:48 cajueiro NetworkManager[844]: <info>  [1590839268.9877] dhcp4 (enp37s0): option routers              => '192.168.1.1'
May 30 08:47:48 cajueiro NetworkManager[844]: <info>  [1590839268.9877] dhcp4 (enp37s0): option subnet_mask          => '255.255.255.0'
May 30 08:47:48 cajueiro NetworkManager[844]: <info>  [1590839268.9877] dhcp4 (enp37s0): state changed extended -> extended
May 30 08:47:48 cajueiro systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
May 30 08:47:49 cajueiro dbus-daemon[843]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
May 30 08:47:49 cajueiro systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
May 30 08:47:49 cajueiro boinc[1281]: No protocol specified
May 30 08:47:58 cajueiro boinc[1281]: message repeated 9 times: [ No protocol specified]
May 30 08:47:59 cajueiro systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Succeeded.
May 30 08:47:59 cajueiro boinc[1281]: No protocol specified
May 30 08:48:30 cajueiro boinc[1281]: message repeated 31 times: [ No protocol specified]
May 30 08:48:31 cajueiro boinc[1281]: No protocol specified
May 30 08:49:39 cajueiro boinc[1281]: message repeated 67 times: [ No protocol specified]
May 30 08:49:39 cajueiro systemd[1]: fwupd.service: Succeeded.
May 30 08:49:40 cajueiro boinc[1281]: No protocol specified




(This white spacing doesn't exist in log, I'm just trying to emphasize the timespan in here. When I got back to the pc it's screens were frozen, keyboard and mouse were totally unresponsive, not even ctrl alt Fx did work, so I shut it down and turned on again)




May 30 10:34:18 cajueiro systemd-modules-load[350]: Inserted module 'lp'
May 30 10:34:18 cajueiro systemd-modules-load[350]: Inserted module 'ppdev'
May 30 10:34:18 cajueiro systemd-modules-load[350]: Inserted module 'parport_pc'
May 30 10:34:18 cajueiro systemd-modules-load[350]: Inserted module 'videodev'
May 30 10:34:18 cajueiro systemd-modules-load[350]: Failed to find module 'v4l2loopback_dc'
May 30 10:34:18 cajueiro systemd-sysctl[417]: Not setting net/ipv4/conf/all/promote_secondaries (explicit setting exists).
May 30 10:34:18 cajueiro systemd-sysctl[417]: Not setting net/ipv4/conf/default/promote_secondaries (explicit setting exists).
May 30 10:34:18 cajueiro systemd[1]: Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...
May 30 10:34:18 cajueiro systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for snap-store, revision 454.
May 30 10:34:18 cajueiro systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for postman, revision 109.
May 30 10:34:18 cajueiro systemd[1]: Finished Flush Journal to Persistent Storage.
May 30 10:34:18 cajueiro systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for vlc, revision 1620.
May 30 10:34:18 cajueiro mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 3: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:03:00.0/usb1/1-5"
May 30 10:34:18 cajueiro mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 2: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:03:00.0/usb1/1-4"
May 30 10:34:18 cajueiro mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 3 was not an MTP device
May 30 10:34:18 cajueiro mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 2 was not an MTP device
May 30 10:34:18 cajueiro systemd-udevd[397]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v245'.
May 30 10:34:18 cajueiro systemd-udevd[397]: ethtool: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
May 30 10:34:18 cajueiro systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for gtk2-common-themes, revision 9.
May 30 10:34:18 cajueiro systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for postman, revision 110.
May 30 10:34:18 cajueiro systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for gtk-common-themes, revision 1506.
May 30 10:34:18 cajueiro systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for snap-store, revision 433.
May 30 10:34:18 cajueiro systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for snapd, revision 7264.
May 30 10:34:18 cajueiro systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for gnome-3-34-1804, revision 33.
May 30 10:34:18 cajueiro systemd[1]: Found device WDC_WDS240G1G0A-00SS50 5.
May 30 10:34:18 cajueiro systemd[1]: Activating swap /dev/disk/by-uuid/00166956-8870-4620-812d-ad6dfd46cabe...
May 30 10:34:18 cajueiro systemd[1]: Activated swap /dev/disk/by-uuid/00166956-8870-4620-812d-ad6dfd46cabe.
May 30 10:34:18 cajueiro systemd[1]: Reached target Swap.
May 30 10:34:18 cajueiro systemd[1]: Listening on Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status /dev/rfkill Watch.
May 30 10:34:18 cajueiro systemd-udevd[414]: ethtool: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
May 30 10:34:18 cajueiro systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Dispatch Password Requests to Console Directory Watch being skipped.
May 30 10:34:18 cajueiro systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Set Up Additional Binary Formats being skipped.
May 30 10:34:18 cajueiro systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in File System Check on Root Device being skipped.
May 30 10:34:18 cajueiro systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Rebuild Hardware Database being skipped.
May 30 10:34:18 cajueiro systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Platform Persistent Storage Archival being skipped.
May 30 10:34:18 cajueiro systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Dispatch Password Requests to Console Directory Watch being skipped.
May 30 10:34:18 cajueiro systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Set Up Additional Binary Formats being skipped.
May 30 10:34:18 cajueiro systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in File System Check on Root Device being skipped.
May 30 10:34:18 cajueiro systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Rebuild Hardware Database being skipped.
May 30 10:34:18 cajueiro systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Platform Persistent Storage Archival being skipped.
May 30 10:34:18 cajueiro systemd[1]: Found device TOSHIBA_HDWD110 YAMATO.
May 30 10:34:18 cajueiro systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Dispatch Password Requests to Console Directory Watch being skipped.
May 30 10:34:18 cajueiro systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Set Up Additional Binary Formats being skipped.
May 30 10:34:18 cajueiro systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in File System Check on Root Device being skipped.
May 30 10:34:18 cajueiro systemd[1]: Starting File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/5984a5af-1d0d-4b38-bc9b-f7233b669a66...
May 30 10:34:18 cajueiro systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Rebuild Hardware Database being skipped.
May 30 10:34:18 cajueiro systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Platform Persistent Storage Archival being skipped.
May 30 10:34:18 cajueiro systemd[1]: Started File System Check Daemon to report status.
```

Comment: Did you check out the *ACPI feature* on the Linux? Look at this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZZBTSUbzT0g)

Comment: [DebuggingACPI](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingACPI)

Comment: [Booting Ubuntu with “acpi=off” grub parameter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139157/booting-ubuntu-with-acpi-off-grub-parameter)

Comment: Tried the config shown in the youtube video, I'll test it for the next few hours, thanks =]

Comment: @jluizsouzadev acpi=force did work for me, thanks! Do you want to "answer" the question? I can't see an option here to "promote" the comment automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was Boinc, that software used to help science projects by processing some workload with our CPUs and GPUs.
There was a persistent error message emmited by Boinc in these logs. Last week I unninstalled it and my computer does not crash anymore.

I'll try some alternative on grid computing.